# How to access QWidget from other threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qwidget

I have

```
struct MyWidget : QWidget {
    // non-GUI related stuff:
    int data;
    int doSth();
};
```

I need to access a `MyWidget` instance from another thread (i.e. not the main thread). Is there any way to do that safely? I understand that I cannot access GUI related functions because some backends (e.g. MacOSX/Cocoa) don't support that. However, I only need to access `data` or `doSth()` in this example. But from what I have understand, there is simply no way to guarantee the lifetime of the object - i.e. if the parent window with that widget closes, the `MyWidget` instance gets deleted.

Or is there a way to guarantee the lifetime? I guess `QSharedPointer` doesn't work because the `QWidget` does its lifetime handling internally, depending on the parent widget. `QPointer` of course also doesn't help because it is only weak and there is no locking mechanism.

My current workaround is basically:

```
int widget_doSth(QPointer<MyWidget> w) {
    int ret = -1;
    execInMainThread_sync([&]() {
        if(w)
            ret = w->doSth();
    });
    return ret;
}
```

(`execInMainThread_sync` works by using `QMetaMethod::invoke` to call a method in the main thread.)

However, that workaround doesn't work anymore for some specific reason (I will explain later why, but that doesn't matter here). Basically, I am not able to execute something in the main thread at that point (for some complicated deadlock reasons).

Another workaround I'm currently thinking about is to add a global mutex which will guard the `MyWidget` destructor, and in the destructor, I'm cleaning up other weak references to the `MyWidget`. Then, elsewhere, when I need to ensure the lifetime, I just lock that mutex.

---

The reason why my current workaround doesn't work anymore (and that is still a simplified version of the real situation):

- In `MyWidget`, the `data` is actually a `PyObject*`.
- In the main thread, some Python code gets called. (It's not really possible to avoid any Python code calls at all in the main thread in my app.) That Python code ends up doing some `import`, which is guarded by some Python-import-mutex (Python doesn't allow parallel `import`s.)
- In some other Python thread, some other `import` is called. That `import` now locks the Python-import-mutex. And while it's doing its thing, it does some GC cleanup at some point. That GC cleanup calls the traverse function of some object which holds that `MyWidget`. Thus, it must access the `MyWidget`. However, `execInMainThread_sync` (or equivalently working solutions) will deadlock because the main thread currently waits for the Python-import-lock.

Note: The Python global interpreter lock is not really the problem. Of course it gets unlocked before any `execInMainThread_sync` call. However, I cannot really check for any other potential Python/whatever locks. Esp. I am not allowed to just unlock the Python-import-lock -- it's there for a reason.

One solution you might think of is to really just avoid any Python code at all in the main thread. But that has a lot of drawbacks, e.g. it will be slow, complicated and ugly (the GUI basically only shows data from Python, so there need to be a huge proxy/wrapper around it all). And I think I still need to wait at some points for the Python data, so I just introduce the possible deadlock-situation at some other point.

Also, all the problems would just go away if I could access `MyWidget` safely from another thread. Introducing a global mutex is the much cleaner and shorter solution, compared to above.

Comment: Please, specify more exactly, what you want to pick from widgets. I think that there will be enough to make requests via signals with arguments throught Qt::BlockedQueueConnection. It will gurantee syncronization, based on Qt events, but may reduce performance.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov: I extended my question. I cannot use `Qt::BlockedQueueConnection`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

```
struct MyWidget : QWidget {
    // some non-GUI related stuff:
    int someData;
    virtual void doSth();   

    // We reset that in the destructor. When you hold its mutex-lock,
    // the ref is either NULL or a valid pointer to this MyWidget.
    struct LockedRef {
        boost::mutex mutex;
        MyWidget* ptr;      
        LockedRef(MyWidget& w) : ptr(&w) {}
        void reset() {
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex);
            ptr = NULL;
        }
    };  
    boost::shared_ptr<LockedRef> selfRef;

    struct WeakRef;

    struct ScopedRef {
        boost::shared_ptr<LockedRef> _ref;
        MyWidget* ptr;
        bool lock;
        ScopedRef(WeakRef& ref);
        ~ScopedRef();
        operator bool() { return ptr; }
        MyWidget* operator->() { return ptr; }
    };

    struct WeakRef {
        typedef boost::weak_ptr<LockedRef> Ref;
        Ref ref;
        WeakRef() {}
        WeakRef(MyWidget& w) { ref = w.selfRef; }
        ScopedRef scoped() { return ScopedRef(*this); }
    };

    MyWidget();
    ~MyWidget();
};



MyWidget::ScopedRef::ScopedRef(WeakRef& ref) : ptr(NULL), lock(true) {
   _ref = ref.ref.lock();
   if(_ref) {
       lock = (QThread::currentThread() == qApp->thread());
       if(lock) _ref->mutex.lock();
       ptr = _ref->ptr;
   }
}

MyWidget::ScopedRef::~ScopedRef() {
   if(_ref && lock)
       _ref->mutex.unlock();
}

MyWidget::~QtBaseWidget() {
    selfRef->reset();
    selfRef.reset();
}

MyWidget::MyWidget() {
    selfRef = boost::shared_ptr<LockedRef>(new LockedRef(*this));
}
```

Now, everywhere I need to pass around a `MyWidget` pointer, I'm using:

```
MyWidget::WeakRef widget;
```

And I can use it from another thread like this:

```
MyWidget::ScopedRef widgetRef(widget);
if(widgetRef)
    widgetRef->doSth();
```

This is safe. As long as `ScopedRef` exists, `MyWidget` cannot be deleted. It will block in its destructor. Or it is already deleted and `ScopedRef::ptr == NULL`.

Comment: A bizarre, paranoid solution, if you ask me.

Comment: When you do multithreading development, you must be paranoid. Every possible deadlock, race condition and what not must be considered.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the signal/slot mechanism, but it can be tedious, if the number of GUI controls is large. I'd recommend a single signal and slot to control the gui. Send over a `struct` with all the info needed for updating the GUI.

```
void SomeWidget::updateGUISlot(struct Info const& info)
{
  firstControl->setText(info.text);
  secondControl->setValue(info.value);
}
```

You don't need to worry about emitting signals, if the recipient is deleted. This detail is handled by `Qt`. Alternatively, you can wait for your threads to exit, after exiting the GUI threads event loop. You'll need to [register](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/custom-types.html) the struct with `Qt`.

EDIT:

From what I've read from your extended question, you're problems are related to communication between threads. Try pipes, (POSIX) message queues, sockets or POSIX signals instead of `Qt` signals for inter-thread communication.

Comment: Yea, basically, that was similar to my current workaround. However, I cannot do that anymore (for some specific, complicated reason). I'll extend my question a bit.

Comment: Why not just wait for the thread to finish at application end? The widget won't get deleted until main thread exits. No need to check whether it exists at all.

Comment: The widget gets deleted when the parents gets deleted, i.e. when its window gets deleted. Or when I remove it from the parent widget.

Comment: The `Qt` default is for the widgets to hide. Removing from a parent won't necessarily delete.

Comment: What about `delete widget`? Or if the parent window was closed (with `WA_DeleteOnClose`)?  The point is, I cannot be sure that it is not deleted.

Comment: You're the programmer, therefore you know, whether it is possible for it to get deleted. You have the option of only hiding it.

Comment: Well, if you want to put it that way: I don't have that option (for various reasons; but doesn't matter here).

Comment: Then do this: connect to the `destroyed` signal and set a flag, after you receive it. This is thread-safe. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#destroyed

Comment: That is already too late then. When I get the `destroyed` signal, that  is already after the `MyWidget` destructor has been called. Also, when I get that signal in another thread, I will get it only with a delay.

Comment: How about my other suggestions? Sockets, msg queues, ...? If you only need data, then that may be the way to go.

Comment: No because it all means that it must block for the main thread, which is not possible.

Comment: Have you heard about nonblocking and asynchronous IO?

Comment: Sure but I might get the main thread blocking for other reasons. I described all the conditions I have. I don't really see what solution you are suggesting. Another thread cannot wait for the main thread to communicate something (see my question). That is a classical deadlock.

Comment: The whole point of nonblocking/async io is, that it doesn't block: you either check for whether data is available or get a signal when it is. Otherwise it is kept in some buffer.

Comment: Yes but the reason the main thread blocks is because it uses some other code which is blocking. I cannot avoid that. Also, async IO is for doing IO, but that is not related to what I'm doing in my main thread. Anyway, I just have those constraints and I cannot change that and I'm asking for a solution with those constraints given.

Comment: IO between threads allows you to decouple them completely. You would not need to sync them (via mutices or otherwise), it would be unnecessary.

Comment: Sure I need. I need to access `MyWidget` from both the main and some other threads.

Comment: You don't understand: if you communicate via sockets, or other means I've enumerated... the threads might belong to different processes, making mutices irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, but I need to access `MyWidget` within the same process from different threads.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I don't like designs where GUI stuff (ie: A widget) has non-GUI related stuff... I think you should separate these two from each other. Qt needs to keep the GUI objects always on the main thread, but anything else (QObject derived) can be moved to a thread (QObject::moveToThread).

Comment: It's basically only a Python object it holds which itself is only GUI related. However, the Python GC might call some traverse function from whatever thread and that traverse function must access the `MyWidget` to visit the Python object.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you're explaining has nothing at all to do with widgets, Qt, or anything like that. It's a problem inherent to Python and its threading and the lock structure that doesn't make sense if you're multithreading. Python basically presumes that any object can be accessed from any thread. You'd have the same problem using any other toolkit. There may be a way of telling Python not to do that - I don't know enough about the cpython implementation's details, but that's where you'd need to look.

> That GC cleanup calls the traverse function of some object which holds that MyWidget

That's your problem. You must ensure that such cross-thread GC cleanup can't happen. I have no idea how you'd go about it :(

My worry is that you've quietly and subtly shot yourself in the foot by using Python, in spite of everyone claiming that only C/C++ lets you do it at such a grand scale.

Comment: Of course that's not possible. However, it is of course possible to somehow introduce a way to access the non-GUI stuff from `MyWidget` in another thread. Actually, if I could just hold a strong ref to it, that would solve it. I wonder why they have no interface for that. But that is just Qts design. I also already described one possible idea to solve this in the end of my question. I actually have implemented that now and it seems to work (needs some more testing).

Comment: They have an interface for it: "don't call `delete`, unless you mean to". Nothing in `Qt` is deleting an instance unless the programmer causes it somehow. `Qt` won't pull the rug from under your feet, unless you ask it to.